# how to extract info out of a column in a table in a website?

Tags: python

**that's all I can manage! I am trying to get proxy's**

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm")

page('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case the table is not really an HTML table, rather plain text wrapped in `<pre></pre>`. You can verify it by looking at the page source.
Anyway, with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) it's a walk in the park:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: from urllib.request import urlopen

In [3]: bs = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm'))

In [4]: print(bs.find('pre').text)

IP address               Anonymity level   Checked time        Country
056.249.66.50:8080       transparent       Apr-21, 10:33       Bulgaria
1.63.18.22:8080          transparent       Apr-21, 05:56       China
1.9.75.8:8080            transparent       Apr-21, 12:58       Malaysia
103.247.219.165:8080     transparent       Apr-21, 04:01       Indonesia
103.4.165.190:80         transparent       Apr-21, 11:34       Indonesia
103.9.126.110:8080       transparent       Apr-21, 12:19       Indonesia
109.173.98.64:8080       transparent       Apr-20, 22:39       Russian Federation
109.197.194.142:8080     transparent       Apr-21, 12:07       Russian Federation
109.207.61.141:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 11:14       Poland
109.207.61.145:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 13:04       Poland
109.207.61.149:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 10:21       Poland
109.207.61.165:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 03:57       Poland
109.207.61.170:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 11:02       Poland
109.207.61.208:8090      transparent       Apr-21, 10:45       Poland
109.224.55.46:80         transparent       Apr-20, 21:50       Iraq
109.227.124.105:8080     transparent       Apr-21, 09:57       Ukraine
109.69.6.118:8080        transparent       Apr-21, 11:44       Albania
110.138.248.135:8080     transparent       Apr-21, 09:10       Indonesia
110.139.13.121:8080      transparent       Apr-21, 11:31       Indonesia
110.159.179.108:80       transparent       Apr-20, 20:35       Malaysia

In [5]: [l.split()[0] for l in bs.find('pre').text.split('\n')[1:]][1:]
Out[5]: 
['056.249.66.50:8080',
 '1.63.18.22:8080',
 '1.9.75.8:8080',
 '103.247.219.165:8080',
 '103.4.165.190:80',
 '103.9.126.110:8080',
 '109.173.98.64:8080',
 '109.197.194.142:8080',
 '109.207.61.141:8090',
 '109.207.61.145:8090',
 '109.207.61.149:8090',
 '109.207.61.165:8090',
 '109.207.61.170:8090',
 '109.207.61.208:8090',
 '109.224.55.46:80',
 '109.227.124.105:8080',
 '109.69.6.118:8080',
 '110.138.248.135:8080',
 '110.139.13.121:8080',
 '110.159.179.108:80']
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Teli\Desktop\ss.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: what **version** are you using

Comment: @user1567728 the latest one. But any version should work. Install it as described [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download).